# Select data based on value of ID

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, chart.js

I am trying to select data based on a value, I have a form which selects data from a table of teams, I need to to get the ID of that row from the select dropdown (which I can do) but then use that to determine the data that it needs to select when im doing an AJAX request. Here goes:

Teams page - This page draws my graph which pulls in data via AJAX to draw the graph and its values:

```
            <form action="teams.php?dashboard_id=<?php echo $dashboard_id; ?>" method="POST">

                <select name="teamId">
                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Please choose...</option>
                <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE dashboard_id = $dashboard_id";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    if($result->num_rows > 0){
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                            echo '<option value=' . $row["team_id"] . '>' . $row["team_name"] . '</option>';        
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                <button class="compare">View</button>
            </form>


            <?php
            if (!empty($_POST["teamId"])) {
                $teamSelect = $_POST["teamId"];
                echo $teamSelect;    
            }else{  
                echo "";
            }
            ?>

            <div style="max-width: 450px;">
              <canvas id="mycanvas" class="container"></canvas>
            </div>
```

Here is the PHP page that im doing the SELECT on:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$teamID = $_POST['teamId'];

$query = sprintf("SELECT
tm.member_id,
tm.team_id,
m.member_id,
m.firstName,
m.lastName,
m.score_1,
m.score_2,
m.score_3,
m.score_4,
m.score_5,
m.score_6,
m.score_7,
m.score_8,
m.dashboard_id,
t.team_id,
t.team_name,
t.dashboard_id
FROM team_members tm
JOIN members AS m
on m.member_id = tm.member_id
JOIN teams AS t
on t.team_id = tm.team_id
WHERE tm.team_id = '$teamID'"); // This need to be dynamic and got from the POST request on the form above.

$result = $conn->query($query);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

$result->close();
$conn->close();
header('Content-type: application/json');
print json_encode($data);

?>
```

Im drawing the graph out via another file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$.ajax({ 
url : "http://localhost/acredashAdv/teamData.php", 
type : "GET", 
success :function(data){ 
console.log(data); 


var chartata = { 
labels: [ 
"Strategic Development and Ownership", 
"Driving change through others", 
"Exec Disposition", 
"Commercial Acumen", 
"Develops High Performance Teams", 
"Innovation and risk taking", 
"Global Leadership", 
"Industry Leader" 
]}; 

var ctx = $("#mycanvas"); 

var config = { 
    type: 'radar', 
    data: chartata, 
    animationEasing: 'linear',
        options: {
         legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom'
        },
         tooltips: {
            enabled: true
        },
        scale: {
            ticks: {
                fontSize: 15,
                beginAtZero: true,
                stepSize: 1
            }
        } 

    },
}, 

LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, config); 

var colorArray = [
    ["#7149a5", false],
    ["#58b7e0", false],
    ["#36bfbf", false],
    ["#69bd45", false],
    ["#5481B1", false],
    ["#6168AC", false]
];


for (var i in data) { 
    tmpscore=[]; 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score_1); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score_2); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score_3); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score_4); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score_5); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score_6); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score_7); 
    tmpscore.push(data[i].score_8); 

    var color, done = false;
    while (!done) {
        var test = colorArray[parseInt(Math.random() * 6)];
        if (!test[1]) {
            color = test[0];
            colorArray[colorArray.indexOf(test)][1] = true;
            done = !done;
        }
    }


newDataset = { 
    label: data[i].firstName+' '+data[i].lastName, 
     borderColor: color,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)", 
    data: tmpscore, 
}; 

    config.data.datasets.push(newDataset); 

} 

LineGraph.update(); 
},  
}); 

});
```

This is all great but in my select query I need the WHERE clause to show me data determined on the value of the team ID and not a static value but im not sure how to pass across the ID from the select back to the AJAX file?

Comment: Are you looking for the WHERE clause keys and values or just the values?

Comment: Im trying to get a select dropdown to be able to select based on that where clause so for instance if my dropdown value is `id_1` and the where clause is `id_1` it will show data from that row. I cant even get that file to see the id yet

Comment: Essentially I want to be able to POST from my select form to the page where the SELECT clause is and then use the value is posts across as the WHERE clause

Comment: Remove sprintf and omit the single quotes: `WHERE tm.team_id = $teamID"`

Comment: Why are you using sprintf with no `%x` http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php ?

Comment: @dev0 that kills the query no errors are reported but nothing is output either

Comment: All I wanna do is use the SELECT option to POST a value say 1 and it be able to be used in another file where the select query is and then that determines the data you seem, I can do it if I manually put the value in

Comment: So when you POST its an associative array, $_POST = "teamId" => "some-value";  Are you not getting the value.  I'm just trying to understand why you cannot get that data.  Seems trivial for the type of code you laid out. If you are referring to Variable variables there is a way to do that.

Comment: @Skippy thanks man, its seriously hard to explain what im doing, basically three files. team.php (has my graph AND form to select team) teamData.php (select query) teamData.js (GET the php via ajax and builds the chart)v - from teams.php I need a way to SELECT the team by ID ad then thats used in the WHERE clause in teamData.php

Comment: @PhpDude I would first try and remove the `sprintf` and see what happens from there. Check your console and your HTML source and var_dump. You should also check for errors on the query, should there be any.

Comment: Any time you have enumerated column names, alarm bells should start ringing. To my mind, it's an infraction of first normal form - but I admit that it requires a somewhat philosophical digression about the meaning of data to explain why.

Comment: So lets less complicate it.  I usually do a fiddle or some sort of simpler way of experimentation without all the moving parts. Create a simple form (php page), and post the data to the same page do a print_r() and see if all that data has posted.  Then use the Keys and Values to build your select query.

Comment: the thing is the whole thing works exactly how I want it to in its current state HOWEVER its just being table to toggle the WHERE value

Comment: If the team id needs to be dynamic use a variable variable.  Like ${$teamID} http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @PhpDude since you're using `type : "GET",` that `$_POST['teamId']` should probably be a GET also. Wish I could provide you with a full solution, but am unable to pinpoint everything.

Comment: Are you not breaking out of the single quote issue.  So for instance.  $a = '$123' will not work.  You need to do $a = "$123" or $a = $123; OR $a = 'some select statement' . $someval . ' continue';

Comment: @PhpDude I take it that `$dashboard_id` has value? Other than that, can't say for sure why it's failing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$dashboard_id` does have a value but that determines the teams available to be selected - I need to pass across or reference $team_id that the file doing the SELECT

Comment: Are you getting any thing from this: $teamID = $_POST['teamId'];

Comment: @Skippy On the team.php yes it outputs the value I want. However I cant reference it on the file where im doing the SELECT. the dropdown on team.php shows me the list of teams aand when I submit that it outputs the value, however I need the graph the show me data from that team id

Comment: Use sessions then.  $_SESSION['teamID'] = $teamID.  Then you can reference it anywhere... Be sure to start the session at the top of each php file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sessions then. `$_SESSION['teamID'] = $teamID`. Then you can reference it anywhere. Be sure to start the session at the top of each php file using sessions.

```
session_start();
$teamID = $_POST['teamId'];
$_SESSION['teamID'] = $teamID;
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: that is the perfect solution i completely forgot I could use sessions

Comment: Glad it clicked.  Sometimes another set of eyes helps... Enjoy!

Comment: Also, look how many people commented, not bad for a -2 down vote.  I'll up vote it ;)

Comment: Yeah man I appreciate everyones support, its exactly that another pair of eyes iv been looking at this all day!

Comment: I'm glad to see this one got resolved. Btw, certainly was not my downvote, *cheers* @PhpDude

Comment: However and if I may suggest, to always test whether or not the session is set/not empty, since it could pose problems later on and to destroy the session once it's not needed as it could cause unexpected results.

Comment: Agreed. handle sessions responsibly ;)

Comment: Hey, iv done it in a way that it unsets it when I leave that page, and also yes does a test if the data isn't present within the session.

Comment: @PhpDude careful; `unset` and destroying a session are two different animals.

Comment: @Skippy I hope you don't mind the edit. The "Let me know" has been replaced with a comment I borrowed from what you posted up there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah man I dont wanna destroy it seems to be working as I want it to is just scraps that until I want it again.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm gonna do some serious testing on this to find any issues form this point and make sure it dosn't *bleep* up

Comment: haha already run into a problem, i moved the files over to another device and ran it locally and it dosn't work! probably to do with unsetting the sessions...

Comment: You don't need to unset or destroy those sessions unless you need to delete them for some reason. I usually keep track of what sessions I have open and if I can I just reuse them or overwrite the values.